# Route only specific subnet through OpenVPN tunnel

Tags: routing, openvpn, pfsense

I know there are many similar postings out there, but none of them could solve my issue.

I have to Sites: A and B which are connected via OpenVPN tunnel.

I would like to route a specific subnet of Site A through the OpenVPN Tunnel connected with Site B.

When, at client side, I configure

```
redirect-gateway def1
```

then ALL traffic of all subnets get routed through this VPN tunnel.

I am using pfSense at both sites.

I also tried adding following option at client side:

```
route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
```

but that does not solve the issue. As soon as I enable `redirect-gateway def1` the traffic of the specific subnet gets routed correctly - but all other subnets get routed as well - this should not happen!

What am I doing wrong? I have configured both sites *exactly* as you can see here: https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/vpn/openvpn/routing-internet-traffic-through-a-site-to-site-openvpn-connection-in-pfsense-2-1.html
Basically, it works! But as mentioned I want this routing to work only for one specific subnet!

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

after hours and days I finally got it working. The key word is **"Policy-Based Routing"**. Basically, you have to define a firewall rule which catches the traffic you want to route and there select the VPN interface as gateway. That's all... It's that easy...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for us:

```
pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway
route-nopull
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```